# How to configure JSON Name Case policy while using MinimalApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, webapi, minimal-apis

I'm trying to get result from my minimal API who configured in endpoints of my MVC web application
my Get action configured like this :

```
            endpoints.MapGet(
                "HO-CFDZU4/api/Currency/Get", 
                [PermissionAuthorize(PermissionName.ReadCurrencyDictionary)] 
                async ([FromServicesAttribute] CurrencyService curency) =>
            {
                var result = await DataSourceLoader.LoadAsync(curency.Get(), new DataSourceLoadOptions());

                return Results.Ok(result);
            });
```

As result i get response with object where property names changed to lowercase, and its not suit for me.
I want to get exactly same name in same case like i return form action.

To get similar effect in MVC i used this code :

```
            services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddFluentValidation(x => x.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("ApplicationCore")).Single()))
            .AddMvcLocalization()
            .AddMvcOptions(options =>{})
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
            });
```

Which setup property naming policy for Json while using action in controllers, and i dont know how to setup same policy for minimalApi.

What Ive tried is to set `[JsonPropertyName(name)]` And it working good but we have lot of classes and i looking for more global solution.

I also tried configure JsonOptions globally like this:

```
        services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
        });
```

But it do nothing

Comment: You return Results.Ok(), if you want formatted json to return use Results.Json() which has optional JsonSerializerOption parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`JsonOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.json.jsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-7.0) from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json` namespace ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#customize-json-binding)):

```cs
services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    options.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});
```

**UPD**

If your application uses both Minimal APIs endpoints and MVC ones, then you try to configure options from both namespaces:

```cs
services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    options.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});
services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});
```

**UPD 2**

Since .NET 7 you can use [`HttpJsonServiceExtensions.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpjsonserviceextensions.configurehttpjsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for "Minimal APIs" ones:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(opts => opts.SerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true);
```

Comment: As I said I already tried similar solution and its do not working for me. And your code snipped do not suit me because I use MVC Core Web application not MinimalApi solution, and in my case services configured just like I pasted in original post.

Comment: @игорьмаркив _"I use MVC Core Web application not MinimalApi solution"_ - your question explicitly says _"while using MinimalApi"_. If you need to use both Minimal APIs and MVC endpoints then setup `JsonOptions` from both namespaces using fully qualified names.

Comment: I mean MinimalApi declaration in MVC WEB Route Endpoints that clearly seen from Code snipped what i provider in original post, but i don't use Separate MInimalApi Solution, and as i says i know how to set JsonOptions  in services using  IMVCbuilder but i dont know how to configure same thing using  IEndpointRouteBuilder

Comment: Your Answer Working after small changes :
builder.Services should be changed to services.Configure