# ASP.NET Core rest API that does return a very big number

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

My project is running on .NET 8 and is using the VS2022 template "ASP.NET Core Web API" as a starting point.

Given the following code and `application/json` as content type:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Numerics;

namespace MyService.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyController > _logger;

        public MyController (ILogger<MyController > logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string GetSupply()
        {
            return "9474488248131986559259619";
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public BigInteger GetSupply2()
        {
            return BigInteger.Parse("9474488248131986559259619");
        }
    }
}
```

The call of `GetSupply` works as expected, and the response body contains

```
"9474488248131986559259619"
```

However since this represents a number I want to get rid of the quotes, so that the response would look like this:

```
9474488248131986559259619
```

Since I do not know how big the number will be I use `System.Numerics.BigInteger`.

`GetSupply2` is returning this datatype, but it results in this response

```
{
  "isPowerOfTwo": false,
  "isZero": false,
  "isOne": false,
  "isEven": false,
  "sign": 1
}
```

which is not my intent.

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: You already had a solution:  Send it as a string and parse it.  Literally any other solution will involve an analogue of "choose a different representation and convert on the consumer side"

Comment: If the supply needs to be a BigInt, what are you selling? :-)

Comment: @Magnus Ethereum

Comment: @possum I do not care. I need to mimic an existing api so the representation is out of my control.

Comment: There are ~120 M Ethereum in circulation which would easily fit in a 32 bit integer

Comment: @Magnus Ethereum is stored in an uint256 datatype. Ethereum has 18 decimals places so your 120 M ethereum is repesented as 120 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 which will not fit in an 32 bit integer.

Comment: @IamanSwtrse ok I see. 18 decimals places seem a little bit overkill though.

Comment: @Magnus for that you have to ask the ethereum consortium. I do not know either. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the reply from [@Guru Stron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501279/guru-stron) i created my own solution. Since the answer did not cover the swagger UI. A few more questions did raise up and I will address them but half of them are swagger related. The answer [@Guru Stron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501279/guru-stron) provided is perfectly fine if you do not care about swagger and only the http response.

The controller I use for my answer looks like

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Numerics;

namespace DfxBackendService.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class StagingController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<StagingController> _logger;

        public StagingController(ILogger<StagingController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public BigInteger GetGmxSupply()
        {
            return BigInteger.Parse("9474488248131986559259619");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public bool PostGmxSupply(BigInteger value) 
        {
            return value == BigInteger.Parse("9474488248131986559259619");
        }
    }
}
```

Out of curiosity I wrote my converter including an valid implementation of the Read function.

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace DfxBackendService.JsonConverter
{
    public class BigIntegerConverter : JsonConverter<BigInteger>
    {
        public override BigInteger Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
            => BigInteger.Parse(reader.GetString()!, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BigInteger value, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
            => writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));

        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) 
            => typeof(BigInteger).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);
    }
}
```

To make use of the converter I added

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new BigIntegerConverter());
});
```

into the Program.cs. Since I do not use Minimal API this was the only thing needed.

Starting from here the http response was correct and just like expected.
However a few things did pop up.

A converter related problem is, when calling the post method `BigIntegerConverter` is not used. For example using `https://localhost:7140/api/Staging/PostGmxSupply?value=9474488248131986559259619` in the browser or with the swagger UI. The Read function is not called instead I end up directly in the `PostGmxSupply` function of the controller. The value is parsed correctly and for the example given the result is `true`. So this is not much of a problem I just want to know why. In an attempt so solve this I also added the `CanConvert` function to the Converter without any effect.

I did however run into 2 swagger related problems.
First the easy one. BigInteger was not rendered as number but as object.
I therefore I changed the line `builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();` to

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.MapType<BigInteger>(() => new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiSchema { Type = "integer" });
});
```

The schema data in swagger.json is then showed correctly.

The second problem is something I did not find a solution for. The swagger UI converts the given number into scientific format. So instead of just showing `9474488248131986559259619` the swagger UI shows `9.474488248131986e+24` and I did not find a way to solve that.

Comment: _"Since the answer did not cover the swagger UI."_ - question has not mentioned it either) Also no need to override the `CanConvert` method, it is handled by the base class. _"using ... in the browser..."_ - you need to create custom binder, JSON serializer settings do not affect how route/query binding works because usually you don't expect JSON there)

Answer (score 4):

`System.Text.Json` (the default library used by ASP.NET Core for JSON manipulation) does not have special handling for `BigInteger` (at least at the moment - see [this issue @github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/60780)), but you can fix this by adding a [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0):

```cs
public class BigIntegerConverter : JsonConverter<BigInteger>
{
    public override BigInteger Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BigInteger value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo), false);
}
```

And then you need to configure options for it to be used by ASP.NET Core:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new BigIntegerConverter());
});
```

P.S.

1. Note that MVC and Minimal APIs use different `JsonOptions` classes (so be sure to configure correct ones) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74889769/2501279).
2. If the goal is to just return the number string as JSON number token then you use `ContentResult` and pass string to it:

   ```cs
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult GetSupply2() =>
       Content("9474488248131986559259619", "application/json");
   ```
3. The [JSON spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-6) does not impose limits on number size and leaves it implementation specific:

   > This specification allows implementations to set limits on the range and precision of numbers accepted.

   So you should consider ability of potential clients to support such big numbers returned by the API and consider to return them as strings to support wider range of clients.

Comment: Already he has the result as string and only problem is to avoid the quotation `""` ... Why parsing it as `BigInteger`  then regenerate the string again ?

Comment: @IbramReda I assumed that this is a test controller representing some subset of actual problem and tried to provide the most generic solution possible. Added option to return string as JSON number token.

Comment: Note that while JSON has no particular constraints on the maximum size of integer literals, most clients which parse JSON won't be able to support integers beyond their biggest integral integer type, probably `long`. They would also have to customise their parsing to use BigInteger or a platform equivalent to be able to parse your response.

Comment: I will look into that after a good night sleep.
My problem is that I have to mimic an existing api interface. So that the clients do not need any change in there implementation.