Newtonsoft custom converter not called in .NET 8 minimal API
We have a version checker API that we're upgrading from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 8 minimal API. It needs to be backwards compatible, but we have run into a problem.
Starting in .NET 6, the default JSON serialization for System.Version changed. We wrote a converter that inherits from Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter.
I tried to add the converter to the application builder, but when the endpoint is called it calls the default serialization instead of the custom code, and I am not experienced enough in this area to see what I'm missing.
How can I adjust this to get the custom serialization?
Expected result:
{"version":{"major":9,"minor":16,"build":6,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1}
Actual result:
{"version":"9.16.2"}
VersionConverter
    public class VersionConverter : JsonConverter<Version>
    {
        public override bool CanRead => true;
        public override bool CanWrite => true;

        public override Version ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Version existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                int major = 0, minor = 0, build = -1, revision = -1;

                while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
                {
                    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
                    {
                        string propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();
                        reader.Read();

                        switch (propertyName)
                        {
                            case "major":
                                major = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
                                break;
                            case "minor":
                                minor = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
                                break;
                            case "build":
                                build = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
                                break;
                            case "revision":
                                revision = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return new Version(major, minor, build, revision);
            }

            throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected token when deserializing Version");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Version value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("major");
            writer.WriteValue(value.Major);
            writer.WritePropertyName("minor");
            writer.WriteValue(value.Minor);
            writer.WritePropertyName("build");
            writer.WriteValue(value.Build);
            writer.WritePropertyName("revision");
            writer.WriteValue(value.Revision);
            writer.WritePropertyName("majorRevision");
            writer.WriteValue(value.MajorRevision);
            writer.WritePropertyName("minorRevision");
            writer.WriteValue(value.MinorRevision);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }

VersionCheckResponse
    public class VersionCheckResponse
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(VersionConverter))]
        public Version Version { get; set; }
    }

Program.cs (simplified)
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new VersionConverter());
});

builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader(HeaderNames.ApiVersion);
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVersionManager, VersionManager>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Configure routing options for case-insensitive endpoints
builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
    options.LowercaseQueryStrings = true;
});

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/version", ([FromServices] IVersionManager versionManager, [FromQuery] string productName, [FromQuery] Version productVersion) =>
{
    ValidationResult<VersionCheckResponse> result = versionManager.CheckVersion(productName, productVersion);
    if (result.IsValid)
    {
        return Results.Ok(new ApiResponse<VersionCheckResponse>(result.Value));
    }

    return Results.BadRequest(new ApiResponse<VersionCheckResponse>(result.ValidationMessage, result.ValidationErrors));
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapHealthChecks("/health");
app.Run();

ADDITIONAL INFO: After the question was closed as a duplicate, I referenced the other question and tried to do the same thing with System.Text.Json. I also modified Program.cs. I get the same result.
VersionJsonConverter
    public class VersionJsonConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<Version>
    {
        public override Version Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            // Handle the case where the input is the string version like "9.16.6"
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
            {
                string versionString = reader.GetString();
                return Version.Parse(versionString);
            }

            // Handle the case for the old format
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
            {
                JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
                JsonElement root = doc.RootElement;

                int major = root.GetProperty("major").GetInt32();
                int minor = root.GetProperty("minor").GetInt32();
                int build = root.GetProperty("build").GetInt32();
                int revision = root.TryGetProperty("revision", out JsonElement rev) ? rev.GetInt32() : -1;
                int majorRevision = root.TryGetProperty("majorRevision", out JsonElement majRev) ? majRev.GetInt32() : -1;
                int minorRevision = root.TryGetProperty("minorRevision", out JsonElement minRev) ? minRev.GetInt32() : -1;

                return new Version(major, minor, build, revision);
            }

            throw new JsonException("Invalid format for Version");
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Version value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            // If you want to serialize in the old format with major, minor, build, revision etc.
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WriteNumber("major", value.Major);
            writer.WriteNumber("minor", value.Minor);
            writer.WriteNumber("build", value.Build);
            writer.WriteNumber("revision", value.Revision);  // Can be -1 if not specified
            writer.WriteNumber("majorRevision", -1);  // For compatibility, you can set these to -1
            writer.WriteNumber("minorRevision", -1);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }


Program.cs modifications
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new VersionJsonConverter());
});


In short - minimal APIs do not work with Newtonsoft Json.NET, for more details please check out the duplicate. Other options would be using "ordinary" controller or writing System.Text.Json converter.

@GuruStron, I have modified the question.

Use builder.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions instead, it is for minimal APIs

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74889769/2501279 for more info

This worked:   builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options =>
{
options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new VersionJsonConverter());
});

If you want to make an answer, I can approve it for you.

Was glad to help!

Feel free to upvote corresponding duplicates if they were useful for you!

Minimal APIs were designed in such way that this is not allowed to switch from System.Text.Json. From the docs:

The body binding source uses System.Text.Json for deserialization. It is not possible to change this default, but JSON serialization and deserialization options can be configured.

There are some workarounds which will allow to cram in the Newtonsoft's Json.NET into Minimal APIs but I would recommend to consider the following alternatives:

Switch to controllers which allows using the Newtonsoft's Json.NET
Rewrite your converter for System.Text.Json

If you will go the second route then you can register the converter via ConfigureHttpJsonOptions (or services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions> for pre .net-7.0 versions):
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(opts =>
    opts.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new VersionJsonConverter())); 

See also:

How to configure NewtonsoftJson with Minimal API in .NET 6.0
How to configure JSON Name Case policy while using MinimalApi

